# Best way to compare two string

Tags: php

I have to make comparison on various features of mobile(about 30 features). But The comparison is to make on basis of values like "800 mAH, Li-ion Battery" .

Suppose a mobile 'A' has battery size '800 mAH, Li-ion Battery'

and second mobile 'B' has battery size 'Li-ion Battery, 400 mAH'

then A is better than B.

So how can I compare 800 mAH, and 400 mAH ignoring rest 'Li-ion Battery',

almost in all 30 features I have to make this kind of comparison. Like I have to make comparison on 4Mb vs 1GB.

Currently I am trying with list($a,$b)=explode() type function.
Is there any better solution.

Comment: Extract the number and compare.

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalize both strings (extract the number/whatever and put in the same units) and compare each on a feature-by-feature basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would depend on the strings. Given the two that you've provided as a limited sample, you could ignore non-numeric characters (also leaving in periods), then compare the numbers.  Something like this:

```
$number_a = preg_replace( '/[^0-9.]/', '', $string_a;
$number_b = preg_replace( '/[^0-9.]/', '', $string_b;
```

Then compare them as numbers:

```
if ( $number_a > $number_b ) {
    ...
}
```

This works so long as you're always comparing the same units, such as you're example shows.  But if the units are different, for instance, "800 mAH, Li-ion Battery" vs. "Li-ion Battery, .4 AH", then it won't.  You'd have to add some more logic to parse through and interpret the units.

Answer (score 3):

How about extracting the number from your string and comparing them

```
$A = filter_var('800 mAH, Li-ion Battery', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$B = filter_var('Li-ion Battery, 400 mAH', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if($A > $B){
// A is better
}
```

Comment: That relies on the units being the same in both comparisons.